# How to prove that $N\setminus A$ is finite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction, cardinals, natural-numbers

$A \subseteq \mathcal{R}(N)$ and given that (by inductive definition):

1. $N ∈ S$.
2. If $a \in R$, then $R \setminus \{a\} \in A$.

I need to prove that for each $A \in S$, $N\setminus A$ is finite. How can I prove this formally?

Comment: You're not *defining* $S$. You're only listing a bunch of properties. $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ itself also satisfies these three properties. You want to argue that $S$ is the smallest set satisfying these three properties. Also you want to write $\Bbb N\setminus A$ and not $\Bbb  N/A$.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you mean that $S$ is *the smallest subset* of $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ satisfying:

1. $\Bbb N\in S$,
2. if $A,B\in S$, then $A\cap B\in S$,
3. if $a\in\Bbb N$, then $\Bbb N\setminus\{a\}\in S$.

There are two ways to approach this:

1. Show that $\{A\subseteq\Bbb N\mid\Bbb N\setminus A\text{ is finite}\}$ satisfies all three properties, and therefore $S$ is a subset of this collection.
2. Show that for every $A\in S$ there are finitely many $a_0,\ldots,a_{n-1}\in\Bbb N$ such that $A=\bigcap_{i<n}\Bbb N\setminus\{a_i\}$, and then apply DeMorgan's law. Or, similarly, show that $S$ can be written as the union of $S_n$'s such that $S_n$ are those given by the intersection of at most $n$ complements of singletons.

You can note that both are *essentially* the same argument, presented in different ways. This is because defining a set via "closure under operations" can be defined as either the intersection of all sets closed an operation, or as a union of sets which are "increasingly more closed under the operation".

---

Note that if you don't mean that $S$ is the smallest such set, but just that "it has these three properties", then the claim is false. $\cal P(\Bbb N)$ also satisfies all three properties, but $\varnothing$ has an infinite complement.

Comment: well that's weird because it was argued that S should be smallest subset of  P(N) satisfying these. but they did say that they define it inductivly, does it help me some how?

Comment: Yes. That's my *repeated* point. You want to talk about the *smallest* set with these properties. Not just "a set" with these three properties.

Comment: but i don't understand how does "defined inductivly" means that S spouse to be the smallest set?

Comment: In this context, I'm guessing that "defined inductively" would be to start with $\Bbb N$ and the complements of singletons, and by induction define $S_{n+1}$ as the intersection of two sets from $S_n$, and $S$ is the union of these sets. If you want *useful* answers, you should provide the information that you have. Not everyone is taking the same course as you, and the language of mathematics, while universal, is sensitive to minor changes "on a local perspective". Be accurate, receive accurate answers. I can't help you unless I know what sort of help you need.

Comment: And it seems that you need to go to whomever is teaching you, and have them explain to you again what "inductive definition" mean in their context.

Comment: Also, send my regards to the Pola bar.

Comment: first thanks for all the help! well here is the definition we have for inductive definition. i get it now.

Comment: the definition : Suppose you have a set S and a function f : N → S which is onto.
Then, we can rewrite S as follows:
S = {f(0), f(1), f(2), ...}
Now, by thinking of the natural numbers as indexes, we can rewrite S
again as follows:
S = {a0, a1, ...}
where ai = f(i). There may be repeats but this does not bother us.
Now we can actually use induction on the indexes of the elements to
prove claims about S.
Let us give an inductive definition of the even numbers:
2N = {a0, a1, a2, ...}
Where a0 = 0 and an+1 = an + 2. Let us prove that the other natural
definition is equivalent.

Comment: a question about the second way to proof it that you gave - how can i actually show that for every A∈S there are *finitely* many a0,…,an−1∈N ?

Comment: That is essentially the inductive definition.

Comment: i understand this is the idea but do i still need to use induction for this based on the inductive definiton or does the inductive defnition include this?

Comment: What is the base for generating $S$ here? Well, $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb N\setminus\{a\}$ for various $a\in\Bbb N$. Can you prove these have finite complements?

Comment: this is clear, i meant if do i still need to use induction in order to show that  for every A∈S there are **finitely** many a0,…,an−1∈N ? can i assume this?

Comment: Well. This is what the inductive definition gives you. You need to justify this somehow. It's not an assumption, it's a consequence. If you could just assume whatever you want, might as well assume the conclusion of everything you want holds.

Comment: yes of course, thanks for all the help!!!